# Compare two workbooks for differencies cell by cell and colouring differencies in second workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, colors, compare

I tried to compare two workbooks which I put with two different buttons in excel and then using third button compare and colour all of the differences red in the second workbook. I'm pretty new in it, but I need it for my work, I currently finished adding two files with similar codes into two buttons:

```
Sub openDialogTemplate()
    Dim ofd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim temwb As Workbook
    Set ofd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With ofd

      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Title = "Please select the Template file."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xlsx"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
      If .Show = True Then
        textFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
      End If
      Workbooks.Open Filename:=textFileName
      Set temwb = ActiveWorkbook
   End With
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub openDialogMaster()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim maswb As Workbook
        
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd

      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Title = "Please select the Master file."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xlsx"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
      If .Show = True Then
        txtFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
      End If
      Workbooks.Open Filename:=txtFileName
      Set maswb = ActiveWorkbook
   End With
End Sub
```

I have no idea how to write a loop correctly using workbooks in temwb and maswb to go cell by cell and color every different cell red in the second workbook.

Comment: I'm presuming that your second workbook (the one where you want to marl the cells) is the **Master** workbook? Also, will both workbooks have same set of data? can you provide a sample of your 2 sheets?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right approach. I'd better use conditional formatting to highlight cells when cells in the first workbook differs from the second one.

You can find more information on [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/highlight-patterns-and-trends-with-conditional-formatting-eea152f5-2a7d-4c1a-a2da-c5f893adb621)

Comment: I agree fully with your answer. However, Microsoft in particular and web sites in general tend to rearrange or otherwise `404` web pages. Please [edit] your post to include some relevant details from the linked site to help the OP along. This is an expected and required activity when answering questions at SO. I will note, though, that maintaining `Conditional Formatting` can become a bit of a nightmare when things get rearranged since it doesn't allow for the use of `Named Ranges` - a sad oversight that properly written code _can_ resolve.